# Moving domain on Django: "Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to"

Tags: python, django

I am running Django 1.8 on a Debian machine. I have previously been running the site with Gunicorn on an old domain. Now I am trying to move it to a new domain.

I have updated the `ALLOWED_HOSTS` setting in my Django settings files, adding  the new domain and removing the old domain. I have restarted Gunicorn using supervisord. However, the site is down (521 error page from CloudFlare).

There are no errors in the Gunicorn logs, so I am starting the debugging process by making sure I can run the Django app.

When I try to run `runserver` with the **new** domain, I see this error:

```
$ python manage.py runserver example-new.com:8000
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 18, 2015 - 11:14:57
Django version 1.7.7, using settings 'example.settings.local'
Starting development server at http://example-new.net:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
Error: That IP address can't be assigned-to.
```

But when I try to run it with the **old** domain it still works, weirdly:

```
$ python manage.py runserver example-old.com:8000
Performing system checks...
System check identified no issues (0 silenced).
June 18, 2015 - 11:16:32
Django version 1.8, using settings 'example.settings.local'
Starting development server at http://example-old.com:8000/
Quit the server with CONTROL-C.
```

I find this very odd, given that I'm certain that `/example/settings/local.py` is up to date, and so are my other settings files.

Is there something else I need to update besides `ALLOWED_HOSTS`? Or do I need to jolt Django into spotting the updated setting somehow?

Comment: I get the same error if I try to run `python manage.py runserver google.com:8000`. So I guess either Django doesn't think that the site is an allowed host, or there's some other permissions error somewhere in my config?

Comment: More debugging: I can bind directly to my IP address with `python manage.py runserver xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8000` just fine. I've set CloudFlare up in front of the new domain. Could that be something do with it?

Comment: If you do `nslookup` on the new domain, do you get an IP returned?  Is that IP an address that's assigned to a local interface?

Comment: Thanks for this. I do see an IP (not the IP of my domain) and if I go there in the browser, I see `Error 1003 / Direct IP access not allowed / You've requested an IP address that is part of the CloudFlare network`. This makes sense as I put CloudFlare in front of the new domain. Do I need to do something special to get Django playing nicely with CloudFlare?

Comment: I haven't used Django with CloudFlare but I'd venture to say that Django is only willing to bind to IPs on local interfaces.  I wonder if your old domain name would be fine to use if all you did is insert CloudFlare...  I assume 0.0.0.0:8000 also works, which just tells Django to listen on all local interfaces.

Comment: `python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000` works, yes, and I can then see the site at http://127.0.0.1:8000 but not at the public IP address.

Comment: Hm, that's a puzzle. I guess I should be using Gunicorn not Django to serve the public site, anyway, so maybe I should focus my energy on debugging why Gunicorn isn't serving?

Comment: True, and maybe someone with more CloudFlare experience can chime in.... does your server still allow direct connections at all or does everything have to go through CloudFlare?

Comment: I haven't whitelisted only the CloudFlare IPs so in theory direct connections should be possible at `direct.example.com`, but in practice that's down too.

Comment: It does seem weird that Django is still happy to serve at the old site when it isn't in `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, though. Still puzzled by that. I even added something to my `manage.py` to print `ALLOWED_HOSTS`, and the old site definitely isn't in there.

Answer (score -1):

It is because you are using the older version. I faced the same problem, updated and it all worked fine!